# Как в PyWebIO input убрать всплывающую подсказку с ранее вводимыми данными?

Tags: python, input

Есть пример простенького чата на PyWebIO. Переделывая его, пытаюсь сделать авторизацию, но при начале ввода в поле чего-либо, всплывает поп-ап с автокомплитом того, что вводилось ранее (что совсем не нужно при вводе пароля). Как от этого можно избавиться? Заранее благодарен за подсказки.

```
import asyncio

from pywebio import start_server
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.output import *
from pywebio.session import defer_call, info as session_info, run_async, run_js

chat_msgs = []
online_users = set()
passwords = set()
MAX_MESSAGES_COUNT = 100


async def main():
    global chat_msgs

    put_markdown("##  Добро пожаловать в чат!\nИсходный код данного чата укладывается в 100 строк кода!")
    msg_box = output()
    put_scrollable(msg_box, height=300, keep_bottom=True)
    # def write_name():
    #         online_users.add(nickname)

    nickname = await input("Войти в чат", required=True, placeholder="Ваш login")
    if nickname in online_users:
        pass
    else:
        online_users.add(nickname)

    password = await input("Войти в чат", required=True, placeholder="Ваш password",
                           validate=lambda n: None if n == '5027' else "Password Wrong!")
    for i in range(len(chat_msgs)):
        msg_box.append(chat_msgs[i])
        i += 1
    chat_msgs.append(('', f'`{nickname}` присоединился к чату!'))
    msg_box.append(put_markdown(f' `{nickname}` присоединился к чату'))

    refresh_task = run_async(refresh_msg(nickname, msg_box))

    while True:
        data = await input_group(" Новое сообщение", [
            input(placeholder="Текст сообщения ...", name="msg"),
            actions(name="cmd", buttons=["Отправить", {'label': "Выйти из чата", 'type': 'cancel'}])
        ], validate=lambda m: ('msg', "Введите текст сообщения!") if m["cmd"] == "Отправить" and not m['msg'] else None)

        if data is None:
            break

        msg_box.append(put_markdown(f"`{nickname}`: {data['msg']}"))
        chat_msgs.append((nickname, data['msg']))

    refresh_task.close()

    online_users.remove(nickname)
    toast("Вы вышли из чата!")
    msg_box.append(put_markdown(f' Пользователь `{nickname}` покинул чат!'))
    chat_msgs.append(('', f'Пользователь `{nickname}` покинул чат!'))

    put_buttons(['Перезайти'], onclick=lambda btn: run_js('window.location.reload()'))


async def refresh_msg(nickname, msg_box):
    global chat_msgs
    last_idx = len(chat_msgs)

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        for m in chat_msgs[last_idx:]:
            if m[0] != nickname:  # if not a message from current user
                msg_box.append(put_markdown(f"`{m[0]}`: {m[1]}"))

        # remove expired
        if len(chat_msgs) > MAX_MESSAGES_COUNT:
            chat_msgs = chat_msgs[len(chat_msgs) // 2:]

        last_idx = len(chat_msgs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server(main, debug=True, port=8080, cdn=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pywebio.input.input](https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/input.html#pywebio.input.input):

> - **type** (*str*) –
>
>   Input type. Currently, supported types are：`TEXT` , `NUMBER` , `FLOAT`
>   , `PASSWORD` , `URL` , `DATE` , `TIME`, `DATETIME`, `COLOR`

```
password = await input("Войти в чат", required=True, placeholder="Ваш password",
                           validate=lambda n: None if n == '5027' else "Password Wrong!",  type = 'PASSWORD')
```